# iOS Firebase propagate custom claims for anonymous auth

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Security Rules for Firestore database I use custom claims check. They work fine. In my app I use anonymous authentication. I followed the instruction, and in my first view I have:

```
[[FIRAuth auth] signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:^(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable authResult,NSError * _Nullable error) { 
FIRUser *user = authResult.user;
NSLog(@"userId: %@", user.uid);}];
```

It works and I get a userId which I can also see in console.Then I use a callable Cloud Functions which adds one custom claim to the user, using it's uid. It works, because in my iOS completion I request getIDToken:

```
[user getIDTokenResultWithCompletion:^(FIRAuthTokenResult *result,NSError *error) {
                                         if (error != nil) {
                                         }
                                         else{
                                             NSLog(@"claims: %@",result.claims);
//here I start my queries}];
```

In this log I see that my custom claim was applied, the uid is correct. Only after that I start my queries to the Firestore database, but I get an error related to Security Rules: **Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions."**

If I stop the app and just restart it with this queries - they work perfectly. So there is no question about the timing. I even postponed my queries for a minute after getting response from Cloud Functions (with claim applied) but in the first time (not restarting the app) queries do not pass security rules.

Is it possible to update Anonymous user in client without restarting the app?

**UPDATE**
Seems to be solved by updating pods to the latest version. In my case I had 5.0.2 and updated to 5.0.5

Comment: Hope you have enabled the Anonymous user login for your firebase project.

Comment: Of couser, otherwise nothing would work: neither Cloud Functions (setCustomClaims) nor iOS code (signInAnonymously, getIdToken)

Answer (score -1):

Here this code for get and set data in firebaseDB.

```
**view.h**
```

@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *refOnline;

```
**view.m**
NSUserDefaults* standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[standardUserDefaults valueForKey:@"UserID"]];
    self.refOnline = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

    self.refOnline =[[self.refOnline child:userID] child:@"isOnline"];
    //[self.refOnline setValue:@"0"];


    [self.refOnline observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);



    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    NSLog(@" %@",[self.refOnline child:@"isOnline"]);

**For Set Value**
[self.refOnline setValue:@"0"];
```

**SET OBSERVER FOR STATUS CHECK**

```
FIRDatabaseReference *observRver =  [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    observRver =[observRver child:[[mutDict  valueForKey:@"UserID"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [observRver observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.value != [NSNull null]){
        NSMutableArray *dict = snapshot.value;


        NSString *isOnline = [dict valueForKey:@"isOnline"];

        if([isOnline isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            cell.img_on_offline.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_on"];
            cell.lbl_on_offline.text=@"Online";

        } else {
            cell.img_on_offline.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_off"];
            cell.lbl_on_offline.text=@"Offline";
        }
      } else {
           FIRDatabaseReference *newRefrence =  [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
          newRefrence =[[newRefrence child:[[mutDict  valueForKey:@"UserID"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] child:@"isOnline"];
          //[newRefrence setValue:@"1"];
          NSLog(@" %@",[newRefrence child:@"isOnline"]);
      }

    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

DATABASE LIKE THIS.
[image]

Comment: I believe it has nothing in common with the question